# Draw a fixed length arrow from point A pointing to B

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

I would like to draw an arrow, with opencv, that originates from a point (X,Y) pointing to a point (X2,Y2) but I would like it to always have a fixed size, regardless of the distance to the second point. I attach an image as an example.

[image]

OpenCV's arrow drawing function always draws connecting the two points, so I tried to use some mathematical formulas for angle, sine and cosine but it was not very clear to me.

Comment: What have you researched?  What have you tried?  Can you draw an arrowed line in OpenCV, see cv2.arrowedLine()?  Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Surely you can solve the simple cases, where the points either coincide, and when the line is vertical/horizontal. For the rest, it's really a case of 2 similar right triangles. Use Pythagoras to calculate the distance between the points, calculate the ratio of this distance to the desired arrow length, scale X/Y offsets of the second point by this ratio to calculate the new end-point, draw the arrow. | Go put some more work in it, show us your code and what exactly isn't working the way you think it should.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parametric form for the equation of a line.

```
X = X1 + t*(X2-X1)
Y = Y1 + t*(Y2-Y1)
```

where t is the normalized length of the arrow that you want. t=0 -> X,Y=X1,Y1 and t=1 -> X,Y=X2,Y2.  Put in t less than 1 will give an X,Y between the two points on the line between them. Put in t greater than one will give an X,Y past X2,Y2 on the extended line between the two points.

So use those equations with cv2.arrowedLine() in Python OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

This is just mathematics.

What you should do is just scaling the directional vector to the your fixed length.

- directional vector **D** = **B** - **A**
- the scaled result **D_scaled** = **D** * ( the_fixed_length / |**D**| )
- tip of the arrow **T** = **A** + **D_scaled**

Draw allow **A** to **T**.